# JS Event Handler: async function

Tags: javascript, cordova, event-handling, async-await

I'm building an app with Cordova. On one page, there is an EventListener that calls an async function. `window.addEventListener("load", loadEdit(), false);`

The function looks like this `async function loadEdit(){...}`.

When testing in the browser I get the following error even though the function is fully executed:

> TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.

However, if I change the EventListener to another function which then calls the async function, there seems to be no problem.
For example:

```
window.addEventListener("load", loadPre(), false);
...
function loadPre()
{
  loadEdit();
}
```

1. What is the problem with an async function getting called by the EventListener?
2. Why does it not detect that the second method also calls an async function?

Comment: Try window.addEventListener("load", await loadEdit(), false);

Comment: Try window.addEventListener("load", loadPre , false); also function loadPre(event)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can call an async function from your `EventListener`.

The first problem I see is that you are invoking the callback function right away in the second argument of `window.addEventListener` by including it as `loadEdit()` instead of `loadEdit` or `() => loadEdit()`. You have to give it a function as second argument, right now you are giving a Promise or the return value of `loadPre()`.

Try this way:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => loadEdit(), false);

async function loadEdit() {
    // do the await things here.
}
```

Async function return Promises. So, if you would like to do something after `loadEdit`, try:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    loadEdit().then(/* callback function here */);
}, false);

async function loadEdit() {
    // do the await things here.
}
```

Comment: I you don't need to do something after loadEdit, why not use `loadEdit` instead of `() => loadEdit()`?

Comment: Or `window.addEventListener("load", async () => { //... code }, false);`

Comment: You have to give it a function as second argument, right now you are giving a Promise or the return value of loadPre(). <-- This is HUGE and made a lot of things connect.

Answer (score 20):

**TL&DR**:  In order to use a call-back with an async function, you will need to decorate your **async** function within the Add Listener, and use await within the code block;

**Explanation:** As mentioned above in your example you are calling the function immediately; This means either two things will happen: Your function will return a value immediately OR you will get a promise; In either case its best to 'await' the call so the program runs more synchronously.

```
async function getStringSize(searchString) {
    return searchString.length
}

txtInput.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    async (e) => {
        const searchString = e.target.value
        total_length = await getStringSize(searchString)
        if (total_length > 3) {
            console.log(searchString)
        }
    },
    false
)
```

Comment: your answer should overrule the top-voted one as it is more modern.