# Calling async function in event listener to load database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, async-await, addeventlistener

I'm trying to load a local sqlite database in a website (on clicking a button). Initially when I used a regular function to load it, I got error in the console. Then I changed it to an async function with await statements and it worked:

```
async function f() {
    const response = await fetch('data.db')
    const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
    const db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buffer))
    console.log(db)

btn.addEventListener('click', f)
```

In most of the places (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623279/js-event-handler-async-function)) inline arrow function has been used inside the event listener:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const response = await fetch('data.db')
    const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
    const db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buffer))
    console.log(db)
})
```

How are the above two codes different from each other? Is it the right way of loading the file?

Comment: `How are the above two codes different from each other?` the value of `this` will be different - other than that, it's two ways to skin the same cat